# Download a ftp file from vbscript without using activeX object

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I want to download a ftp file using vbscript code. I am using the following code:

window.open("ftp://10.237.225.175/securityNT.reg")

To download this file in IE7, i have to enable automatic prompting for file downloads in the Internet options-> Security -> Internet -> Custome level. I have to download the file without enabling it in vbscript. Please suggest the solution for this. I cant use an activex object for this.

Answer (score 1):

Shell out (.Run, .Exec) and use ftp.exe with a suitable command file (-s:filename option).